# Django - form is never valid

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm creating a form without model. Here is my form class:

```
class LinkAssetsForm(forms.Form):
    preview = forms.ChoiceField()
    thumbnail = forms.ChoiceField()
    banner = forms.ChoiceField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(LinkAssetsForm, self).__init__()

        filepod = kwargs.get('filepod',None)

        if filepod is not None:
            fp_util = FilePodUtil()
            preview_files = fp_util.get_files_from_filepod(filepod, ['mov'])
            thumbnail_files = fp_util.get_files_from_filepod(filepod, ['jpg'])        
            banner_files = fp_util.get_files_from_filepod(filepod, ['jpg']) 
            self.fields['preview'].choices = [(x.fullpath, x.name) for x in preview_files]
            self.fields['thumbnail'].choices = [(x.fullpath, x.name) for x in thumbnail_files] 
            self.fields['banner'].choices = [(x.fullpath, x.name) for x in banner_files]
```

My template:

```
<form role="form" id="form-content" class="form-horizontal" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}

    {% bootstrap_form form layout="horizontal" %}

    {% url 'delivery:delivery-detail' delivery.id as cancel_url %}                  

    <div class="form-group formAction">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9">
            <div class="rc-faGroupPrimary">
                {% bootstrap_button "Save" button_type="submit" button_class="btn-primary" size="lg" %}
            </div>
            {% bootstrap_button "Cancel" button_type="link" button_class="btn-default" href=cancel_url %}
        </div>
    </div>              
</form>
```

In my view:

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    form = LinkAssetsForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():

        print 'VALID=====>>>>>>>>>>'

        data = form.cleand_data
        #TODO: save the data

        messages.add_message(self.request, messages.SUCCESS, "Assets linked successfully.")
        return redirect(reverse('delivery:delivery-content-link-assets', args=[self.kwargs['delivery_id'],self.kwargs['content_id']])) 
    else:
        print 'INVALID=====>>>>>>>>>>'
        messages.add_message(self.request, messages.ERROR, "Select all the required fields.")
```

My problem is that the form never passes the `if form.is_valid()` condition. The form renders properly, I choose the value in the combo boxes, submit to the right address, etc.. and it always fails the validation.

Can you see what I am missing?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: did you know you can print errors? like print form.errors. Add us the error and it will be quicker to help you :)

Comment: use `print 'INVALID=====>>>>>>>>>>', form.errors` to see the errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have forgotten to pass args and kwargs when you call `super()`. It should be:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(LinkAssetsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did that intentionally because I was passing some  variables via kwargs to the form and it was throwing errors at the super class. Now I have removed the method from the __init__ and now I have a better error message. It says: Select a valid choice. diagram.png is not one of the available choices. I think now it is just missing the choices on post. But the error is better now

Comment: If you construct the form with extra kwargs, then you can pop them before calling `super()`, e.g. `filepod = kwargs.pop('filepod')`.

Comment: Yeah, I just had to fill the options again on post. Thanks, your answer solved the issue!

Answer (score 1):

You could try to add

```
{{ form.errors }} 
{{ form.non_field_errors }}
```

to template display the errors - this could give you a hint.

P.S. "clean**d**_data" - is it a typo?

Comment: .non_field_errors: <bound method LinkAssetsForm.non_field_errors of <LinkAssetsForm bound=False, valid=False, fields=(mezzanine;preview;thumbnail;banner)>> . I'm starting to think about a URL problem

Answer (score 0):

I've found in cases where the form is never being validated, it is because it's requiring all fields in cases where they are not always necessary. Setting required=False inside your form fields i.e.:

```
banner = forms.ChoiceField(required=False)
```

may help if you won't always be passing in values to the fields.